# AzureDevOps: Pass task variable to subsequent powershell task type as Object

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I want to create a Pipeline that is copying files from one Azure subscription to the next one in one Azure DevOps Pipeline.

For this I have setup my pipeline yaml and my two powershell scripts where the parameters are created via logging commands and passed to the second powershell task as arguments.

Pipeline.yaml

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    ScriptType: filePath
    ScriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Task.ps1'
    azureSubscription: 'Sub1'
    azurePowerShellVersion: latestVersion
  displayName: 'Task 1'

- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    ScriptType: filePath
    ScriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Task2.ps1'
    azureSubscription: 'Sub2'
    azurePowerShellVersion: latestVersion
    ScriptArguments: >
      -DestAcc "$(DestAcc)"
      -DestKey "$(DestKey)"
      -DestContext "$(DestContext)"
      -DestStorageContainer "$(DestStorageContainer)"
  displayName: 'Task 2'
```

Task1.ps1

```
$location="germanywestcentral"
$rg="rg1"
$StorageAccountName="storage1"
$StorageSku="Standard_ZRS"
$StorageKind="StorageV2"
$StorageContainer="blobcontainer"

$StorageAccount=Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $StorageAccountName
$storageAccountKey=(Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $StorageAccountName).Value[0]
$StorageAccountContext=$StorageAccount.Context

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DestStorageContainer;]$StorageContainer"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DestKey;]$storageAccountKey"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DestContext;]$StorageAccountContext"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DestAcc;]$StorageAccountName"
```

Task2.ps1

```
param (
    [string] $DestStorageContainer,
    [string] $DestUrl,
    [string] $DestKey,
    [object] $DestContext,
    [string] $DestAcc
)

$subscriptionId=(Get-AzSubscription).Id
$resourceGroupName ="rg2"
$diskName = "DD"
$DestFileName="Filename"

$DestAcc=$DestAcc
$DestContainer=$DestStorageContainer
$DestKey=$DestKey
$DestContext=$DestContext
$sasExpiryDuration="3600"


Start-AzStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $sas.AccessSAS -DestContainer $DestContainer -DestContext $DestContext -DestBlob $DestFileName
```

Now the problem is that the parameter $DestContext will be formatted to type string instead of being the type "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.LazyAzureStorageContext". The whole error message in the pipeline is the following:

> Cannot convert the "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.LazyAzureStorageContext" value of type "System.String" to type "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.IStorageContext".

I then started to work on the problem and installed the "Az.Stroage" module to the runner while execution the powershell task. But this did not solve the issue as I am setting the type of the object inside the PARAM section and not after the import of "Az.Storage" module.

Does anybody know if this is possible? Is there a way that I can pass the Azure Storage context object to the next task via task variable? Or change the type from string to the Azure Storage context type?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test with the same PowerShell and reproduce the same issue.

When you set the value in Pipeline variable, it will show as String type.

I'm afraid there is no method to keep the object form in a variable.

To meet your requirement, I suggest that you can add the command in Task2.ps1 to get the context in the same task.

`New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "ContosoGeneral" -StorageAccountKey "< Storage Key for ContosoGeneral ends with == >"`

Here is an example:

```
param (
    [string] $DestStorageContainer,
    [string] $DestUrl,
    [string] $DestKey,
    [object] $DestContext,
    [string] $DestAcc
)

$subscriptionId=(Get-AzSubscription).Id
$resourceGroupName ="rg2"
$diskName = "DD"
$DestFileName="Filename"

$DestAcc=$DestAcc
$DestContainer=$DestStorageContainer
$DestKey=$DestKey
$sasExpiryDuration="3600"

$Context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "ContosoGeneral" -StorageAccountKey "< Storage Key for ContosoGeneral ends with == >"

Start-AzStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $sas.AccessSAS -DestContainer $DestContainer -DestContext $DestContext -DestBlob $Context
```

You can use the Storage Account key to access the storage account in different subscription.

Comment: Will this be adressed in future? Since in my opinion it would be great to pass variable with the correct object type.